# Superset UI cannot be loaded on port 9089 in HDP sandbox and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ambari, apache-superset, hdp, opensearch-dashboards

I'm unable to load Superset in Ambari on port 9089. Even the initial login screen won't get displayed. The URL is shown as http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:9089.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the URL from http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:9089 to http://localhost:9089 or http://127.0.0.1:9089 fixed my issue and was able to load Superset UI in Ambari.